# MySQL - PHP - Avoiding multiple queries to count results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to get some results for a query and count all the data results using PHP.

Actually I'm doing something like this:

```
$MQ=$cnx->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE field=1;");
$MFA=$cnx->fetch_row();
$count=$MFA[0];
echo "Showing $count results";
$MQ=$cnx->query("SELECT id,name FROM table WHERE field=1;");
while($MFA=$MQ->fetch_assoc()){
  // show something with $MFA[id] and $MFA[name]
}
```

I want to avoid using 2 queries, Is there any way to get the rows count and **then** get all the results without using an array?

Comment: You could just count the results as you process them.

Comment: Since you're using mysqli, have you tried using [num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)?

Comment: @Uueerdo, I need the count before process them.

Comment: @EduardoGalván , I think that is the way, can you show me an example? I tried using num_rows, it gave me the count, but I couldn't run the while to print the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) property to get the number of rows in a result set.

```
$MQ=$cnx->query("SELECT id,name FROM table WHERE field=1;");
$count=$MQ->num_rows;
echo "Showing $count results";
while($MFA=$MQ->fetch_assoc()){
  // show something with $MFA[id] and $MFA[name]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

> Is there any way to get the rows count and then get all the results without using an array?

There is, but you don't need it.

In fact, **you should use an array**, to separate your business logic from presentation logic.

And as long as you have an array, you can always count it's members.

You definitely should quit the practice of showing the query results right during the query execution. Instead, learn logic separation and use of templates.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know it was a bad practice, Now I have to edit all my PHP files.

Comment: This is just his opinion, I don't think it's a concensus.